# Clicar em carregar mais e aumentar o LIMIT

Tags: php, jquery, html

Quero fazer uma query para quando eu clicar no botão carregar mais, o LIMIT aumente para exibir mais 9 imagens em minha galeria
Meu Código:

```
<!-- connect.php -->
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$db = "fenix";
$pass = "";

try{
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Error ".$e->getMessage());
}

<!-- index.php -->
<?php
    require_once("connect.php");
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#carregar_mais").click(function(){
        <?php $limite = $limite + 9;?>
    });
});
</script>

<?php
    $results = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM arquivo ORDER BY id_arquivo DESC LIMIT $limite");
?>

<div class="imagens">
    <?php   
        while($row = $results->fetch(){     ?>
            <a href="upload/uploads/<?php echo $row['nome_arquivo'];?>" > 
                <img class="imagem" src="upload/uploads/<?php echo $row['nome_arquivo'];?>" />
            </a>                                    
    <?php } ?>                       
</div>

<center>
    <p id="carregar_mais" style="color:white; cursor:pointer;">Carregar mais</p>
    <?php echo $limite;?> <!-- Este echo é só para exibir em quanto está meu LIMIT-->
</center>
```

Ao carregar a página aparecem 9 imagens. Quando eu clicar em "carregar mais" devem aparecer mais 9 (18). É como um scroll infinito, porém o usuário decide quando carregar mais imagens.

Obrigado!

Comment: Cuidado com sql injection, quando usar variável `$limite` diretamente na query. A propósito javascript, não é server side, não dá para fazer isso desse jeito.  Como dizia, Cole Sear, "Eu vejo SQL Injection o tempo todo..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está a fazer confusão na ligação de JavaScript com PHP. O JavaScript é executado do lado do browser e o PHP é executado do lado do servidor.

O seu limite só incrementa do lado do servidor. Pode é através do javascript fazer um novo pedido ao servidor com mais 9.

Corrigi também a sua ligação à DB. Está a fazer confusão entre mysqli e PDO.

```
<!-- index.php -->
 <?php
         require_once("connect.php");
         //recebe input do ?limite no URL
$limite = (isset($_GET['limite'])) ? $_GET['limite'] : 9;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#carregar_mais").click(function(){
       //novo pedido ao servidor com +9
       window.location.href = '/index.php?limite=<?php echo $limite+9;?>';
   });
});
</script>
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM arquivo ORDER BY id_arquivo DESC LIMIT $limite";
   $data = $connect->prepare($sql);
   $data->execute();
?>

<div class="imagens">
<?php
   $results = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   foreach($results as $image)
     {
?>
     <a href="upload/uploads/<?php echo $image->nome_arquivo; ?>" >
        <img class="imagem" src="upload/uploads/<?php echo $image->nome_arquivo; ?>" />
   </a>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<center>
   <p id="carregar_mais" style="color:white; cursor:pointer;">Carregar mais</p>
   <?php echo $limite;?> <!-- Este echo é só para exibir em quanto está meu LIMIT-->
</center>
```

Em alternativa pode utilizar AJAX para fazer um pedido ao servidor sem fazer refresh à página.

Comment: Só uma dúvida. Esta técnica só funciona se estiver hospedado? Na hora que eu clico em Carregar Mais ele me redireciona para uma página do XAMPP (http://localhost/dashboard/)

Comment: @Matheus convem testar o seu código num servidor Apache. O XAMP serve perfeitamente.